# What is the English translation of "quizá el de qué..."?

Tags: gramática, sustantivos

For context, the full sentence I am trying to understand is "Su vida de ermitaño era un enigma, *quizá el de qué secretos ocultaba*, cómo podía haber vivido seis décadas sin desafíos notables."

I understand most of the sentence - my rough translation is "His life as a hermit was an engima, ..., how he had been able to live six decades without notable challenges." It's the middle part that is confusing me. "Maybe what secrets were hidden/he hid" is the best I can come up with, but that doesn't seem to make much sense. How would this segment translate into English?

Comment: I would say; `who knows how many...`

Answer (score 2):

> *"Su vida de ermitaño era un enigma, quizá el de qué secretos ocultaba, cómo podía haber vivido seis décadas sin desafíos notables."*

In the comment *«quizá el de qué secretos ocultaba»*, the article *el* stands for *el enigma*. This is a type of [nominal ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)#Nominal_ellipsis). The article refers to the noun *enigma* that has just been mentioned:

> *...un enigma, quizá el **enigma** de qué secretos ocultaba...*

It's basically the same as in English, if you allow for that *el* being translated as "the one".

Note that *enigma* is masculine; that's why you use *el* in the ellipsis. If you want to drop a feminine noun, you must use *la* instead (and you must of course use *los* or *las* if the noun is plural, masculine o feminine respectively).

The rest of the phrase (*«...de qué secretos ocultaba»*) is subordinated to that elliptic *el* (meaning *el enigma*). So the whole means "...an enigma, the one (=the enigma) of what secrets he was hiding".

There seems to be an unspoken "or" as well; the enigma was maybe (*quizá*) the secrets he was hiding **or (else)** how he could have lived... etc.